# SQL Server Compact 4.0 code-first with connectionstring specified

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I have a simple console application setup and I am trying to get code-first Entity working properly. I've done the basic examples and have set up my classes and context. Once I run my application the database is auto generated and placed in my `bin/Debug` directory. That's great so at least something works. But now I want to add a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database file (`.sdf`) to the project and use that instead of the autogenerated database. From what I've read I just need to add a connection string with a name that matches the derived `DbContext` class.

Below is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=Database1.sdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And this is the error I am receiving when it tries to use the initialize the context.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

The inner exception says

> Configuration system failed to initialize

I've tried specifying the context directly though the constructor, and still no luck.  Hopefully, I am just overlooking something.

(Side note, I grabbed EntityFramework from Nuget and it should be 5.0, yet the appconfig says 4.4? The autogeneration works great so I figured they didnt have anything to do with each other.)

Comment: EF 5.0 on a .NET 4.0 will be called `4.4` - nothing wrong here (just confusing numbering schemes....) EF 5.0 will be `5.0` on a .NET 4.5 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in my connection string I was pointing to a location that didnt exist. Hence every time I would run the program it would create a file in the bin/debug automatically.

So either specify a direct file path to the sdf file or use |DataDirectory|

```
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf"
```

Then peak at what your directory is set to. If its not the directory in your application, then you will need to change this manually. But Websites have an App_Data directory that it should point to.

```
  var s = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
```